# Wordpress function add code to the <body>

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need add codes to my body tag via function in my custom plugin.

This code I need add

```
id="#test" ondragstart="return;" ondrop="return;"
```

the final form should look like this

```
<body id="#test" ondragstart="return;" ondrop="return;" <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Adding an ID to `body` is a bit too much IMHO. First, if it already has an ID (which is rare - reason see below), there will be a problem, and second, there can be only *one*  `body` element, so you can always select it by its tag, and also use that (`body ... ...`) in combined selectors.

Comment: BTW, you wouldn't write `id="#test"`, but `id="test"`. The hash is only used in CSS and jQuery selectors, its not part of the ID

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the hook `body_class`, here is the documentation on Wordpress website, [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/).

And here is your code to trigger the function to change the body class:

```
function add_body_class( $classes ) {
    return array_merge( $classes, array( 'your-new-class' ) );
};
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_body_class');
```

The function `add_body_class` will return the existing body class plus the new class `your-new-class`.

Comment: add_body_class will only add classes. In other words this doesn't really answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: You can edit `header.php` of your theme

Option 2: Using `jQuery`

```
$("body").attr("id","#test").attr("ondragstart", "return;").attr("ondrop", "return;");
```

Comment: His question refers to adding a plugin so option one won't work and option two as it stands won't work either because $ is not defined.  Option two could work if it were written out correctly.